# Grails Routes - ignore css, js and images

Tags: grails, routes, url-routing

How do you get UrlMappings to ignore /css, /js and /images when you have added a route like this

**UPDATE**

```
"$username"(controller:"profile",action:"show") {
        constraints {
            username(notInList:['css','js','images'])
        }
}
```

Can I use notInList? I how do I reverse inList?

Comment: Could not get this to work either -            constraints {
                username(matches:"^css|^js|^images")
            }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.6%20Mapping%20Wildcards):

> If you are using wildcard URL mappings then you may want to exclude certain URIs from Grails' URL mapping process. To do this you can provide an excludes setting inside the UrlMappings.groovy class:

```
class UrlMappings = {
    static excludes = ["/images/*", "/css/*"]
    static mappings = {
        …
    }
}
```

This allows you to exclude directories from the mapping.

**Update** If you want to use a regex, this might work better:

```
constraints {
    username(matches:"^(?!(js|css|images)/).*")
}
```

This regex matches anything that *doesn't* start with `js/`, `css/`, or `images/`.  It matches via *zero-width negative lookahead* (`(?!…)`.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that. Curious, to why my code fails though. this is the last route in my UrlMapping.groovy file besides the 500 error route. Shouldn't a constraint prevent it from being processed. I though I at least had my regexs correct.

Comment: Actually, your regex *only* matched things that started with `css`, `js`, or `images`.  A better regex would be `^(?!(js|css|images)/).*` - which is a negative lookahead to not match `js/`, `css/`, or `images/`.  It allows strings that *start* with js, css, or images, however.

Comment: aww yep. Nice catch. Thanks +1 Going to use the excludes. Much easier.

Comment: I am using Grails 3.0.1 and it seems that "excludes" no longer works .. https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-12041